# Keep FFMPEG processing if input fails

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to save a stream to a video file. If the input stream goes down, FFMPEG automatically stops encoding, but I want to somehow still display those seconds in which the input is down (as a black frame or freezing the last frame).

What I have tried:

```
ffmpeg -i udp://x.x.x.x:y -c:v copy output.mp4
```

I wonder if it is possible to keep writing the mp4 file even if the input goes down.

Comment: No, that is not a feature of ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

You need to code a special application for this.
It will take the input (will re-encode it if necessary) and will output to ffmpeg.
In the special app, you can check whether is the source is offline or not and act accordingly.

Crucial thing here is PCR values must be continuous, this is why this kind of thing is hard to do or code in general. But it can be done.